# Word for "feeling the same as someone"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for when you feel the same as someone, you see them in yourself or you are in the same situation?

I think it starts with the letter C.

Comment: hmmm ... connected [!], conjoined?

Comment: a sample sentence please!

Answer (score 9):

You may be trying to think of [commiserate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/commiserate), but I think [empathize](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/empathize) is a better fit.

Answer (score 7):

[**Empathy**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/empathy) [ˈɛmpəθɪ]
*n*

> **1.** the power of understanding and imaginatively entering into
>   another person's feelings
>   **2.** the attribution to an object, such as a work of art, of one's
>   own emotional or intellectual feelings about it
>
> [from Greek *empatheia* affection, passion, intended as a rendering of German *Einfühlung*, literally: a feeling in; see EN-, -PATHY]

Answer (score 3):

[Compassion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compassion) may be the word you're thinking of. Someone who has compassion is sensitive to the feelings of others:

> Deep awareness of the suffering of another, coupled with the wish to relieve it

However, compassion does not necessarily mean one has been in the same situation. [Empathy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/empathy) may more strongly convey the meaning you want, because it usually means that you can imagine yourself in another's shoes, or if your empathy is born of experience, that you have gone through the same hardships. Someone with empathy has:

> capacity to understand another person's point of view or the result of such understanding

Comment: You should have put *empathy* first, and not been misled by OP thinking his target word started with C. *Compassion* is efectively the same thing as *sympathy* here, and the difference between *sympathy* and *empathy* is central to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If 'C' is the initial, then *compassion* comes closest.

However, by definition, **sympathy** is the word that fits: 'feeling the same as'. It is sad that the word is more popularly understood as 'pity', which is just another meaning for it.

Look up *sympathy* in dictionaries for its definition.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with those who said you were probably thinking of "commiserate".

Another term can be relate.
When you relate to someone.

> relate to 
>  Feel sympathy for or identify with. ‘kids
>   related to him because he was so rebellious’
>  [Oxford Living
>   Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/relate)

relate to can also mean to share in another persons circumstances.

> "I've been made fun of my whole life. I don't know if that's something
>   that you can relate to."
>   [Link](http://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/someone-can-relate-to-a-feeling)