# Word for "knowing the feeling from X situation"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Yes, I know the same thing [has been asked before](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43515/word-for-feeling-the-same-as-someone), but there were no answers that fit the word I'm trying to find.

Anyway, what is a word for "knowing the feeling from X situation"? That would be something like "know that feel" in slang. I am not thinking of *sympathy* or *empathy*.

It is more like: let's say someone describes a situation like "and then I feel sad because of what is said", and I know myself from it or I know the feeling very well. Sorry if I'm not very good at explaining. Hope someone knows what I am talking about. If it is of any help, I would say "å føle seg truffen" in Norwegian.

#### I think I'll stick with something like "I <strike>recognize</strike> know that feeling" or "I can relate".

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with "sympathy"? It means almost exactly what you have described.

Comment: Well, maybe I should correct it, because it is more like "knowing the feeling from X situation". Well, it is kind of hard to explain, as english isn't y primary language.

Comment: I would use "I _know_ that feeling," not "I _recognize_ that feeling." _Recognize_ implies that you can perceive it, without necessarily ever experiencing it first-hand. If someone is cursing on the golf course and throwing his clubs around, anyone can _recognize_ that he's angry. But if I tell him, _"I know that feeling,"_ that would imply that I've been frustrated on the golf course, too. In such situations, _know_ implies _can relate to_ while _recognize_ does not.

Comment: You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it could be "likewise".
It can be used in many cases, when someone expresses some feeling/opinion, and you want do say that you feel/think the same.

E.g.:
A: It was a pleasure talking to you.
B: Likewise. (it was a pleasure for me as well)

A: I feel sad for this.
B: Likewise. (I feel sad too)

Etc.

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking something like that. And those who up voted this answer too seem to have got the question wrong. OP might clarify.

Answer (score 1):

In casual conversation, if someone related feelings to me which I had experienced before, was familiar with, and was made to feel by the description - I would be most likely to say something like *I know what you mean*, e.g.

> Person A: ... and it made me feel completely ashamed.
>
> Person B: I know what you mean.

When describing such situations rather than participating in them (I'm not sure which you are asking about), a simple and common option is to say that you **feel for** the other person.

For instance, if I said something like:

> Casey was telling me all about her breakup; I really felt for her.

it would imply not only that I was sympathetic, but that, as you said, I knew her particular feelings well myself.

Comment: Another alternative for "I know what you mean" might be "I can relate."

Comment: ^ Good point. I think "can relate" works well for the second scenario, actually (*I could really relate to Casey's experience*) but not so much for the first - as Person B, I would be reluctant to say "I can relate" for fear that Person A will think I am self-centeredly turning the conversation toward my own experiences, rather than being a good listener. Still, it's certainly something people do say in that context.

Answer (score 0):

So simple.

I tell my friends, be it guys or girls, “I feel you, bro.”

Answer (score 0):

I would say something like *commiserate*, which means “to express sympathy or pity”.

Comment: Try to include a useful definition, explanation, usage examples from a reliable source with citation. So that it doesn't appear like a personal opinion or a guess.

Comment: I’m not sure that sharing someone’s misery always applies to sharing their feelings.  They are more feelings than misery.

Answer (score 0):

"That really **resonated** with me."

"I **empathise** with that."

"I can **identify** with you there."

Long story short, there doesn't appear to be a word in English (as far as I can see) for knowing the feeling from an arbitrary situation. You have to use little phrases instead, such as the ones above.